# JQuery Toggle button to turn function on or remove it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I am trying to create a toggle checkbox for a site that will toggle the colors of the site. Instead of changing the css file being linked, I would like to call a function to change the css of elements background colors and colors, then when the toggle is clicked again, the site reverts back to its original state. I've tried using jQuery `on()` and `off()` but not having much luck so far. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
function toggleColor() {
    $('section').css('background-color', '#fff');
    $('section').css('border', '3px solid #000');
};

$('.switch input:checkbox').change(function(){
    if ( $(this).is(":checked") ) {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        toggleColor();
        console.log('ON');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        console.log('OFF');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

I have also tried this:

```
$('.switch input:checkbox').on('click', toggleColor );

$('.switch input:checkbox').off('click', toggleColor );
```

I have been able to call my toggleColor function, but is there a way to kill off or disable the changes I have made using css properties. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to change the theme of your website, why do you not want to load a different css file and reload the page?

Comment: Just add a class when you check your checkbox and remove this class when you uncheck and add CSS a this class.

Comment: Thanks, for now I ended up adding a second css file to append my current one when toggled.

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
<style>
   .new-css{
       background-color: #fff;
       border: 3px solid #000;
   }
</style>
```

(of course put your styles in your css file)

and :

```
$('.switch input:checkbox').change(function(){
    if ( $(this).is(":checked") ) {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $('section').addClass("new-css");
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $('section').removeClass("new-css");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create another function to reset the added CSS and invoke the function on unchecking the checkbox.

```js
function toggleColor() {
    $('section').css('background-color', '#cdcdcd');
    $('section').css('border', '3px solid #000');
};

function removeColor() {
  $('section').css('background-color', '#fff');
  $('section').css('border', 'none');
}

$('.switch input:checkbox').change(function(){
    if ( $(this).is(":checked") ) {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        toggleColor();
        console.log('ON');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        removeColor();
        console.log('OFF');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
</section>
```